# Refactoring code with static listeners

Tags: android, static, refactoring, listener

After some debugging I found the following thing in existing *production* code:

```
public class SomeTTS {
    private static TTSSpeechListener mSpeechListener;
    private static TTSBreakListener mBreakListener;
    // more static (!!!) listeners
    private String mPath;

    public TTS(String path, TTSSpeechListener speechListener)
            throws RuntimeException {
        // ...
        mSpeechListener = speechListener;
        mBreakListener = null;
        // more listeners set to null
        // ...
    }
    // called from NATIVE code that I cannot change
    private static void onReceiveSpeechData(byte[] samples) {
        mSpeechListener.onSpeechData(samples);
    }
    // ...
}
```

The class is a wrapper for a native library (Android, NDK, JNI). I have no access to the native library source. (You, of course, see the problem: after I create a 2nd instance of `SomeTTS`, the 1st instance does not work anymore.) I am a bit shocked: I would not expect such bugs from anyone but a schoolboy. Probably they were using child labor. Or, more likely, someone could not explain the difference between a demo and production code to his manager.

Anyway, I have to make it work. I have some thoughts, but what I can propose at the moment is far from perfect. Any ideas how to refactor it?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did: I left the class broken and wrapped it in a class providing a sensible API.

Since it is TTS, and it is reasonable to let TTS speak out only one request at a time, I used a static pointer to the current SomeTTS instance, and made the invocations synchronized. I could not fix the `SomeTTS` class, but I could make sure that my invocations of its methods are correct -- which by the way meant that I do not invoke some methods.

```
public class SomeTTS {
    private TTSSpeechListener mSpeechListener;
    // ... more listeners, NOT static ...

    private static volatile SomeTTS currentTTS;
    protected static Object currentTtsAccessLock = new Object();

    public static TTSSpeechListener currentSpeechListener() {
        synchronized (currentTtsAccessLock) {
            return currentTTS == null ? null : currentTTS.mSpeechListener;
        }
    }
    public static void setCurrentTTS(SomeTTS tts) {
        synchronized (currentTtsAccessLock) {
            currentTTS = tts;
        }
    }

    // called from NATIVE code that I cannot change
    private static void onReceiveSpeechData(byte[] samples) {
        TTSSpeechListener speechListener = currentSpeechListener();
        if (speechListener != null) {
            speechListener.onSpeechData(samples);
        } else  {
            // Just no better idea. But this should never happen.
            Log.e("SomeTTS","ERROR: speechListener == null  samples: "+samples.length);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

That's all with this class. It is still possible to make incorrect calls to its methods; the discipline is to use `MyTTSEngine` instead. That class, `MyTTSEngine`, provides a sensible API; `SomeTTS` does not.

```
class MyTTSEngine {
    private SomeTTS mTTS;
    private Object upperLevelTtsLock = new Object();

    // ...

    public void say(String text) {
        // ...
        synchronized (upperLevelTtsLock) {
            TTS.setCurrentTTS(mTTS);
            try {
                mTTS.clearAbortState();
                mTTS.synthesizeFromString(text);
            } finally {
                TTS.setCurrentTTS(null);
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```